# Automating the addition of many HTTP layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, http

I would like to know how to automate the addition of many HTTP layers in QGIS. I have a lot of layers in GeoJSON with a HTTP, like "http://localhost:8080/otp/traveltime/isochrone/?location=43.60665,3.88178&cutoff=PT1H&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&time=2022-11-02T10:17:42%2b00:00" generated with an other software which add polygons. I can have many HTTP layers, but I would like to open them all in the same time (and not add one by one in QGIS). Here in Excel an example of only ten lines:
[image]

How can I add all the layers in the same time (with a script or a plugin)?

Comment: Is your list of layer URLs a simple textfile with one URL per line?

Comment: I created many URLs where each one will request a software and generate polygons in my QGIS. I can arrange them in a textfile as a list for example, or separated with a comma.

Comment: I use the plugin « Catalog on the fly » to load multiple « http layers ».